# `responses.add` different responses for same request?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm using `responses.add` with `unittest`. For a unit test I'm writing, I want a different response for second time the same request is made. (The request is querying the status of some task, and I want to test a function that checks multiple times for the task to be finished.) Is this possible?

Comment: Is the function being tested making a genuine query, or are you using unittest to provide fake/mock results?

Comment: I'm using mock/fake responses from the server.

Comment: Then it should be relatively easy; you just need a way to provide a particular fake response on the fly, instead of a single monolithic fake response.